# MSc with relation to Cloud

Tags: masters

I wonder if there are universities having real-world MSc related courses. My focus is to understand cloud technologies and services(especially if it is Amazon). Preferably in UK, but can be actually anywhere around the world. Maybe general or specific like PAAS , SAAS etc. Could you suggest any?

Comment: Try the National College of Ireland - MSc Cloud Comouting. They have a state of the art Cloud centre

Comment: This is a "shopping question" that dates from when the site was first forming, and didn't yet have a standard against such questions.  As such, I have voted to close.

Answer (score 2):

There's an MSc specialising in Networks and Distributed Systems at [St Andrews](http://www.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/?q=node/47). There's also quite a large group that does cloud computing research and a [cloud lab](http://www.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/stacc), so you would almost certainly be able to do an MSc project on that topic.

Answer (score 1):

At the [K.U. Leuven](http://wms.cs.kuleuven.be/cs/) there is a lot of research done in distributed systems, with a recent focus on cloud computing. You could do a Masters in Distributed Systems and do your thesis on an issue related to cloud computing.  (One would need to first check that the course could be done in English.)